# validation on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a submit button like this:

```
<input class="create_button" name="commit" 
       onclick="return validate_activity();" 
       type="submit" value="Save">
```

I found that this button will always send request to the server whatever the validate_activity() return true or false?

What's the problem here?

**UPDATE**

Actually, I made a mistake in my validate_activity(), it makes me think it returned false, but it not.

Comment: Can you post what you have on `validate_activity()`?

Comment: Right, I made a mistake in my validate_activity().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try doing same without return, e.g. `onclick="validate_activity();"` and check if your function returns false in case of invalidity

Comment: Will this also work on a submit <button> instead of a submit <input>?

Comment: This won't prevent anyone from submitting the form, e.g. by pressing Enter on an input field in the same form.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
<form action="...." onsubmit="submitForm()" name="form">

<input type="submit" value="Save">

</form> 


function submitForm(){

    if(validationfails){

        return false;
    }
    else  {
        document.form.submit();
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="button" name="commit"
value="Save"
onclick="validate_activity(myform)" />
```

Inside the Javascript, when validated, do `form.submit()` or else return false.

I hope this helps ! This will validate your form and submit it. This submit will fail if the Javascript is disabled in your browser.

if you want the submit to proceed even if the javascript is disabled in the client browser ( means no validation but will submit), then

```
<input type="button" name="commit"
value="Save"
onclick="validate_activity(myform);return false;" />
```

I hope no validation shouldn't hit you at all. But then javascript is just client side and I hope you will have serious sanity checks on the server side anyways and of many, I think people use it for very basic field checks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `submit` event of the form for validation..

```
<form action="..." method="..." onsubmit="return validate_activity()">
    <...>
    <input class="create_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
    <...>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is `onclick="return validate_activity();"`, this return statement gets executed when clicking the submit button (not return false).
The correct way is  `onclick="validate_activity();"` and return false in `validata_activity` function, which will stop the default submit action.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing form validation then validating it on button's `onclick` event, the way you're are trying makes no sense better you should use it on `<form></form>` `onsumbmit` event like this.

```
<form action="someURL" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_activity();">

</form>
```